# SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflow - Failed on Start (Retrying)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have built a simple workflow on SPD 2013 for a custom list, it's the first workflow on the entire site collection. When the workflow is triggered, the workflow status says that it has "**Failed on Start(Retrying)**". The workflow does not run.

Does anyone have a solution to this? Is there some sort of configuration have missed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First and importantly check all your correlation tokens. make sure that each task (Creation, Updating and Completing) has its own Token not the workflow token.
Then compare the dll you have with the one in the workflow.xml and the one in the GAC. simply they all should be the same.

Try this on the command prompt:
 `Lodctr` `“c:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.0\Windows Workflow Foundation\perfcounters.ini”`

And if it doesn’t work for you try: `Lodctr /R “c:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.0\Windows Workflow Foundation\perfcounters.ini”`

Answer (score 0):

There might be the issue in case of after installing .NET security patches to the SharePoint Server.

Please refer below link for the issue caused and solution for the workflow.

[**Link1**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rodneyviana/2018/09/13/after-installing-net-security-patches-to-address-cve-2018-8421-sharepoint-workflows-stop-working/)

Answer (score 0):

First step is to check the error. You can find the details by pointing the `i` with the mouse.

[image]

I often had error 401 or 403. 
Furthermore, I use the [ULS-Viewer](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=ulsviewer) getting more information using the correlation id.